# CUARTA DERIVADA: mi gráfico es incorrecto

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.7, matemáticas

Parece ser que la gráfica que estoy imprimiendo en la terminal está incorrecta, sinceramente ignoro si puede ser un error fuera de mi conocimiento, pero ya revisé el código repetidas veces y no puedo encontrar el error.
Para la cuarta derivada, esta es mi codigo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi=np.pi
x=np.arange(0,5*pi,0.03*pi)
y=np.cos(x)

h=x[4]-x[3]

"Cuarta derivada"

#Primer formula

der41=[]
x41=[]

for i in range(2,len(y)-2,1):
    der41.append((y[i+2]-4*y[i+1]+6*y[i]-4*y[i-1]+y[i-2])/(h**4))
    x41.append(x[i])

der41=np.array(der41)
x41=np.array(x41)

#Segunda formula

der42=[]
x42=[]

for i in range(3,len(y)-3,1):
    der42.append((-y[i+3]+12*y[i+2]+39*y[i+1]+56*y[i]-39*y[i-1]+12*y[i-2]+y[i-3])/(6*h**4))
    x42.append(x[i])

der42=np.array(der42)
x42=np.array(x42)

plt.plot(x,y,'g',x41,der41,'r',x42,der42,'b')
plt.title("Cuarta derivada")
plt.xlabel("Eje X")
plt.ylabel("Eje Y")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Esta es la gráfica:

[image]

Este código está basado en las siguientes formulas:

[image]

Las dos derivadas y la ecuación inicial deben tener la misma "forma".

Answer (score 1):

La [segunda fórmula](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/home.html) [está mala](http://web.media.mit.edu/~crtaylor/calculator.html), por eso el gráfico de `(x42,der42)` es diferente del resto. La fórmula con los signos corregidos de los coeficientes es:

```
( -f[+3] +12f[+2] -39f[+1] +56f[0] -39f[-1] +12f[-2] -f[-3]) / ( 6h**4)
```

Realizando la correspondiente modificación en el código

```
der42=[]
x42=[]

for i in range(3,len(y)-3,1):
    der42.append((-y[i+3]+12*y[i+2]-39*y[i+1]+56*y[i]-39*y[i-1]+12*y[i-2]-y[i-3])/(6*h**4))
    x42.append(x[i])

der42=np.array(der42)
x42=np.array(x42)

plt.plot(x,y,'gs',x41,der41,'r*',x42,der42,'b')
plt.title("Cuarta derivada")
plt.xlabel("Eje X")
plt.ylabel("Eje Y")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Tenemos:

[image: Gráfico final de las cuartas derivadas]